# Custom Sidebar only on single post

Tags: functions, widgets, sidebar, register-sidebar

I am developing a child theme for the new twenty thirteen theme and I am trying to add a sidebar (widget area) next to my content. I only want it to display in `single` posts.

What I did: edit single.php (and add it to my child theme's folder) like so:

```
get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php /* The loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

                <?php get_sidebar('sidebar-3'); ?> <!-- DOESN'T WORK -->
                <!-- /END of sidebar-aside-content -->
                <?php twentythirteen_post_nav(); ?>
                <?php comments_template(); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And registered the sidebar in functions.php, like so:

```
function mobiel_informatie_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar next to content', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-3',
        'description'   => __( 'Wordt naast een single post weergegeven.', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'mobiel_informatie_widgets_init' );
```

The thing is that I can see this widget area in Appearance >> widgets, but no matter what I add, nothing ever show in the template. I am guessing I'm doing something wrong with the `name` reference, but the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar) aren't really clear on that in my opinion.

### EDIT1:

Here are some images to illustrate my problem:

*The code of my single.php*

[image: The code of my single.php]

---

*The widget in WP, works fine*

[image: The widget in WP, works fine]

---

*The output -- nothing is outputted*. There should be something before the `/END` comment.

[image: The output -- nothing is outputted]

The only thing I can think of why this wouldn't work, is because of a conflict with the parent theme (twenty thirteen). It has twee sidebars, written in functions.php, like this:

```
/**
 * Registers two widget areas.
 *
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 *
 * @return void
 */
function twentythirteen_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Main Widget Area', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Appears in the footer section of the site.', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Secondary Widget Area', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
        'description'   => __( 'Appears on posts and pages in the sidebar.', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentythirteen_widgets_init' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In additon to wordpresser answer, you can also call to get_sidebar('sidebar-aside-content'); only in the template files where you want the sidebar be displayed. For example, if you include

```
<?php get_sidebar('sidebar-aside-content'); ?>
```

in "theme_folder/single.php" file, the sidebar will be displayed only in single posts.

For example. In functions.php:

```
//Register your sidebar
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widgets_init' );
function my_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'The title of my sidebar', 'curioso' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-mysidebar',
    'description' => 'An optional widget area for my sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</div>",
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
 ) );
}
```

Now you have to create a file named sidebar-mysidebar.php and put it in you theme folder. This file will load the widgets. For example:

```
 <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-mysidebar' ) ) : ?>

   <div class="mysidebar">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-mysidebar' ); ?>
   </div>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

Now in the file of your theme where you want 'mysidebar' be displayed:

```
<?php get_sidebar('mysidebar'); ?>
```

Comment: Please consider my edit. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I think you have missed the template part for the new registered sidebar. I've edited my answer.

Comment: As you can see in my edit, in the first picture, I have added the line `<?php get_sidebar('sidebar-3'); ?> `. It's right there, in my template file `single.php`.

Comment: Have you read again my answer? I've edited it with complete information.

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't know it had to have its own template file! Thanks again!

Comment: You are wellcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php get_sidebar('Widget Area Next to Content'); ?>
```

should be

```
<?php get_sidebar('sidebar-aside-content'); ?>
```

to display only on single posts

```
<?php if(is_single) get_sidebar('sidebar-aside-content'); ?>
```

Comment: `is_single()` is a function, and should be written as such

Comment: Please consider my edit. It still doesn't work.